# How to fix php crud not showing detail page in table view by id

Tags: php

Iam setting up detail page view in my application by getting id the detail page id not giving me a data to my front end. any example. anyone give me some sample.

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: im using only core php.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use any framework, then you should create the detail page manually. let's say the url was :

/detail.php?id=x

then inside the detail.php, you can get the parameter

```
$param = $_GET['id']
```

and the query would be

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM detail WHERE id=?");    
$stmt->bind_param("s",$param);
$stmt->execute();
```

and you can display all the data with foreach

Comment: but its not showing data, here is my snippet  http://snippi.com/s/d08puls . i dont know what is the wrong iam doing here.